# GUI tool for configuring Java property files

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, configuration, properties

Is there any? Ideally I can somehow give the tool a list of property names, also data type and default value for each property.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using XML and property list files, you might want to use the [Preferences](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class, instead. If you take a look at the [Java Project Template](http://code.google.com/p/java-project-template/), it includes the ability to do what you want (using the Preferences class):

- The option "--prefset name=value" sets the preference key "name" to "value".
- The option "--prefget name" causes the value for preference key "name" to be printed.
- The option "--prefdel name" causes the key "name" to be removed.
- The option "--preflist" causes all the preferences for the application to be printed.

Comment: Hi Michael. I downloaded your project but didn't see any documentation for it. There is only source files in there as well.

Comment: Hi, bonga. That is a valid criticism. I will add documentation.

Comment: Ok. I added documentation. Please see the following link: http://code.google.com/p/java-project-template/wiki/Basics